# Gallery losing focus bug

Tags: android, focus, gallery

I have dialog with 2 horizontal galleries and one `LinearLayout`, and i have problem with `focus`.

It looks like this:

---

### Gallery 1

### Gallery 2

### LinearLayout

Gallery 2 is some kind of submenu of Gallery 1.

I've implemented `onItemSelected` listener for both galleries. When i select something in Gallery1 content of Gallery 2 is changed and focus stays on Gallery 1. And it work fine.

When i select something in Gallery 2 i have to inflate xml file in `LinearLayout` and do something with that.

Problem is when i select something in Gallery 2, and inflate xml in LinearLayout...focus goes on Gallery 1, but I need it to stay on Gallery 2, until I press Up or Down or whatever. Don't know what is the problem, it makes no sense to me.

Do you have some idea?

`Gallery2.requstFocus()` doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've forgot about this problem, 'couse i've gave up :)
But recently i had a similar problem and solve it...

The fact is that requestFocus command doesnt have time to done its work if your GUI is complex.

Its a Android bug...

I've solve similar problem with some kind of finite state machine and threads to update focus.

I have one variable which represent states, for focus...which item has to focused.
I have made one thread for each state.
In thread I do something like this:

item1.clearFocus();
item2.clearFocus();
item3.requestFocus();

Hope you understand what I want to say.

In my app when i need to focus particular item, i just start the "updating focus thread" for that item.

Thats all, hope u solve yours problem.